# Javascript in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie to React. Currently, I'm working on fetching a Google map to my page. I was going through the Samples from the Google Maps platform and stumbled upon this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

I was asking if there is any way to use this code in my React project using only JavaScript, HTML, and CSS to render the map on the browser.

Thank You

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I just have the basic project configured using npx create-react-app

Comment: yes, but we still need to see it so that we can tell what's wrong and what's what

Comment: look out for npm libraries, which can support googlemaps with react. Hope there are 2-3 libraries.  https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps Hope the link will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the google map api's using npm. `npm install --save react-google-maps`.
For reference, you can check out [here](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#installation)